# Using AWS S3 and DynamoDB to make an instagram clone instead of Parse

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-platform, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to consider AWS as an option now that Parse is shutting down.

My question is when creating a social network, similar to instagram, AWS S3 for photo/video storage combined with DynamoDB for the database (friend connections, URL reference to photos in S3) would be a viable choice? Are these two products together roughly equivalent to what Parse offers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not an expert in this topic but i would like to share my opinion. aws is more than capable for satisfying the needs of most applications. (as far as i know parse was using aws for their infrastructure, i cant give a reference though)
drawback here is that the learning curve is much more steeper compared to what parse offered. also in my opinion documentations of the sdk has a lot room for improvement.

i was developing an app which is kind of a social network using parse and most of the work was done when parse announced the bad news. after a long research i decided to migrate to aws. i am using cognito for authentication, dynamodb for data storage, lambda for "cloud code", s3 for "pffile" and sns for push notifications. as far as i have seen these services combined completely substitutes for parse, however it is harder to implement

i hope this was helpful

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I am also moving from Parse to AWS. I am sharing my learning experiences in a blog series,beginner level, http://peterfennema.nl/exploring-aws-as-a-backend-for-a-swift-app-1/

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, are you content with the decision you've made? You could have chosen other alternatives like running Parse-Server on AWS+MongoDb or Heroku+MongoDB.

Comment: I can say that I am. For migrating a production environment, running a parse server could have made more sense but in my case depending to a sdk of a company that is shutting down seemed like a bigger risk